# (Closed) Error on apt-get update (sury.org) [linux]

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, virtualmin

I'm trying to `apt-get update` on my virtualmin (debian) but it fails with some package (packages.sury.org)

then I check the package with:

```
curl --verbose -SLO https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3_8.41-1+0~20170825202309.5+jessie~1.gbp97d153_amd64.deb
```

And it throw:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 00:37:49 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 16
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=df716884f5fd8ee4d658ae79b60f1589416669; expires=Sat, 13-Jun-20 00:37:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.sury.org; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
< Cache-Control: max-age=15
< Expires: Thu, 14 May 2020 00:38:04 GMT
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
* Server cloudflare is not blacklisted
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 59308d88e98bcd8f-CDG
< alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-25=":443"; ma=86400, h3-24=":443"; ma=86400, h3-23=":443"; ma=86400
< cf-request-id: 02b236c9940000cd8fb3200000001
< 
{ [data not shown]
```

How can I solve it?

---

> Edit: Solution

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

then run: `apt-get update`

That works for me! hope it helps someone in the future :)

Source: https://df.tips/t/topic/334

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I'm getting `ERROR: The certificate of ‘packages.sury.org’ is not trusted.` on the wget command so can't reach the .gpg file.

Comment: Please flag an answer as solution. Do not embed the solution in your question :)

Comment: Also probably not related to "linux" tag in general. We can remove that tag.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue which was fixed by redownloading the gpg key:

```
wget https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg

sudo apt-key add apt.gpg
```

After this you can update or install your packages.

Answer (score 2):

For older Debian version like stretch, I solved it by adding this repository

```
deb http://mirror-bbg-5.internet1.de/sury-php-stretch stretch main
```

in the following file

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

Then added the repository key

```
wget -qO - https://debian.octopuce.fr/sury-php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
apt update
apt install php8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at [packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/pcre3/](https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/pcre3/), you can see that package

```
libpcre3_8.41-1+0~20170825202309.5+jessie~1.gbp97d153_amd64.deb
```

doesn't exist.

The current version in jessie's [Packages](https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages) list (amd64, 13-May-2020 07:12) is

[libpcre3_8.43-1+0_20190710.6+debian8_1.gbpbfc49f_amd64.deb](https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3_8.43-1%2B0~20190710.6%2Bdebian8~1.gbpbfc49f_amd64.deb)

Comment: I retry `apt-get update` and it throws: `W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.sury.org jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B188E2B695BD43`

Comment: It looks like somethings wrong with `packages.sury.org` Right?

Comment: Something's wrong with the key and your package list is outdated. I'd try this script: [packages.sury.org/php/README.txt](https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt) (and remove the old sources list if the filename is different).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue (inside gitlab-ci docker container drud/ddev-webserver) where error was:

> The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B188E2B695BD4743 DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key

To fix the error, I just download the new key:

```
apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

And then run package update

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```